# Cannot load linux or u-boot in QEMU

Tags: linux-kernel, qemu, u-boot

I am trying to use QEMU to load u-boot so I can interface with the console there. The ultimate target for u-boot does not have a serial port, so the easiest way I can interface with the u-boot console is via an emulator.

When I run the emulator with these flags, the emulator starts, but nothing is printed to the console:

`qemu-system-ppc -nographic -M virtex-ml507 -cpu 440epx -kernel u-boot.bin -dtb virtex440-ml507.dtb -serial mon:stdio -append 'console=ttyS0'`

This is a combination of the suggestions found [here](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/u-boot-for-arm-on-qemu/) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/471719/how-to-start-qemu-directly-in-the-console-not-in-curses-or-sdl).

I have attempted running the program without the -nographic flag, but receive the error `gtk initialization failed`.

I have also tried running the emulator with more "standard" inputs:

`qemu-system-ppc -nographic -M virtex-ml507 -cpu 440epx -kernel zImage -dtb virtex440-ml507.dtb -initrd ramdisk.image.gz -serial mon:stdio -append 'console=ttyS0'`

You might note that I am using a `zImage` there instead of `bzImage`. Currently, when I build the kernel, there is no `bzImage` produced. In the interests of thoroughness, I have also subbed in `vmlinux` for `zImage` to no avail.

I have also tried running the emulator without the `-serial` and `-append` flags, allowing the emulator to handle I/O, as described in the first guide.

QEMU seems to run correctly i.e. not hang, since I can still enter the command mode as well as exit normally. It seems like this is an entry point issue, but I would figure entry points would be handled by the emulator, and I haven't seen any guides telling me to specify them. It may also be that the files I'm using are broken in some way, since I haven't ran them on anything else, but my builds complete seemingly correctly.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the suggestions you're trying to combine are (a) a recipe for running u-boot on Arm and (b) suggestions for setting serial output for x86. Different CPU architectures vary a lot here, and I would not be surprised if neither of those was particularly useful for PPC. My first guess is that the u-boot.bin binary is not expecting to be started in whatever way QEMU's -kernel option for PPC starts binaries.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to bear in mind is that in general, U-Boot and QEMU and PowerPC only has been known to work for the 'qemu-ppce500' build target, and that is a different CPU family than the 440 that you're targetting above.  All of that said, when trying to do what you're doing, for PowerPC you need to use the -bios flag and the argument is the **u-boot**  file that is built.  You do not need nor want to pass -dtb, -kernel, nor -append.